# Is this the right way to save a boolean in sharedpreferences?

Tags: android, boolean, sharedpreferences

I want to save a boolean value to shared preferences. Then I convert the value of the boolean to a string and fill a textview. It works fine by this code. But if I remove the app from the emulator, the boolean value is lost. So I want to know, if it is the right way how I save the boolean.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
public TextView bool;
public boolean enabled;
public Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean enabled = prefs.getBoolean("key", false);

        TextView bool = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bool);
        String theValueAsString = new Boolean(enabled).toString();
        bool.setText(theValueAsString);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        changeBoolean();
         SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean enabled = prefs.getBoolean("key", false);
        TextView bool = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bool);
        String theValueAsString = new Boolean(enabled).toString();
        bool.setText(theValueAsString);

    }

    public boolean changeBoolean(){
         SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        enabled =  true;
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("key",enabled).commit();
        return enabled;

    }

}
```

Thanks for help!

1. Is this the right way to save a boolean to sharedpreferences?
2. Is it correct, that my data is lost, if I reinstall the application?
3. I don't unterstand this line:

   boolean enabled = prefs.getBoolean("key", false);

Why is there false? Is it automatically changed, when I save to the sharedpreferences?

Comment: SharedPreferences operates on a "SandBox" only to your application. when you delete/remove the application all the data saved inside this Sandbox get deleted too.

Comment: Thanks, what happens, if I upload an update? Is an update safe?

Comment: Yes it is. no problem updating your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the right way to save a boolean to sharedpreferences?

This works, if you intend `changeBoolean()` to always save the value `true` and not "change" the value.

> Is it correct, that my data is lost, if I reinstall the application?

Reinstallation keeps your app data. Only if you uninstall or explicitly choose to clear the app's data is the shared preferences also lost.

> I don't unterstand this line:
>
> ```
> boolean enabled = prefs.getBoolean("key", false);
> ```
>
> Why is there false? Is it automatically changed, when I save to the sharedpreferences?

The second parameter is the default value. `getBoolean()` returns it in case there was no value saved for `"key"` in the shared prefs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to set the boolean

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(you_pref_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putBoolean(YOUR_KEY, you_boolean_value);
    editor.commit();
```

to get the boolean use :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(you_pref_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getBoolean(YOUR_KEY, false);
```